# entity framework query, how to select more than 1 table?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

i have this query

```
var resultado = from c in conn.carrera
                            join u in conn.usuario on c.idusuario equals u.idusuario
                            join t in conn.texto on c.idtexto equals t.idtexto
                            where c.estatus == 1
                            select c;
```

how do i get something as it:

```
select c.*,u.*,t.eltexto from carrera c
join usuario u on c.idusuario =u.idusuario
join texto t on c.idtexto = t.idtexto
where c.estatus = 1
```

you could see in the query i am `select c.*, u.* and t.col1,` then
how can i get it in EF? because my first query gets only `carrera.*` but i need more data.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily return a new object consisting all the properties of the three joined tables:

```
var resultado = from c in conn.carrera
                            join u in conn.usuario on c.idusuario equals u.idusuario
                            join t in conn.texto on c.idtexto equals t.idtexto
                            where c.estatus == 1
                            select new
                            { 
                               c.prop_1, 
                               c.prop_n, 
                               u.prop_1, 
                               u.prop_n, 
                               t.prop_1, 
                               t.prop_n 
                            };
```

Comment: thank you i am checking what about select new{c,u,t.col_i_want};

Comment: That also works, however its always a good practice to only select the columns you need

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.*,u.*,t.eltexto from carrera c
join usuario u on c.idusuario =u.idusuario
join texto t on c.idtexto = t.idtexto
where c.estatus = 1

from c in Carrerra
join u in Usuario on c.idusuario equals u.idusuario
join t in Texto on c.idtexto equals t.idtexto
where c.estatus = 1
select new {
  newcolumn1 = c.column1,
  c.column2,
  usercolumn1 = u.column1,
  usercolumn2 = u.column2,
  textcolumn = t.column1
}
```

if you want access to the objects themselves, then you could do

```
select new {
  usario = u,
  carrera = c,
  texto = t
}
```

Carrera, Usario, and Texto refer to the Models in your Entity Framework container.